# Fragments not showing content on viewPager scroll - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, fragment

I'm new to Android..
I am trying to create a simple application with a sliding tab to scroll between 2 fragments. The fragments are populated with dummy buttons just to see if the scrolling works. However when I run all I see are the viewPager indexes on top without the fragments. I am also using these two files SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java that are given by Android. Here are my classes:
MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
package billdozer.com.testxml;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // Holds tab titles
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Frag #1", "Frag #2"};
    private Context context;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    // Return the correct Fragment based on index
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return new TabFragment1();
        } else if(position == 1) {
            return new TabFragment2();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Return the tab title to SlidingTabLayout
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
   }
```

TabFragment1.java

```
 package billdozer.com.testxml;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

TabFragment2.java

```
    package billdozer.com.testxml;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

tab_fragment_1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

tab_fragment_2.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_9" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_11" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/_12" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.billdozer_ui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.user.billdozer_ui.stab.SlidingTabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));

        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user.billdozer_ui.MainActivity">

    <com.example.user.billdozer_ui.stab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" />
</LinearLayout>
```